# Get file extension while using file_get_contents() in PHP

Tags: php, google-places-api

Im retrieving images from thee google places API on my PHP server by using the following lines of code

```
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
```

I'm also writing this file onto a folder on the server like so: (The file returned is a binary file, not an image file)

```
    file_put_contents($folderPath,$response);
```

How do I find out the file extension of the file I read into $response?

I have tried the following:

```
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $size = getimagesize($response);
    $extension  = image_type_to_extension($response)
```

Comment: When you `file_put_contents` does it save with the extension?

Comment: So `$response` is the actual image and not the file name, what sort of URL are you passing?

Comment: The url is something like this "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=1080&photoreference=<Some photo reference>"

Comment: No, it does not save with extension, infact since the file has no name to begin with, it does not save until i give it a name myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try pathinfo

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

it should help you

[EDIT]
Since your image is returned as binary, then use php's getimagesizefromstring   http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php

It will return all the details you need.

Comment: The file returned is a binary file, and it does not work in this case. pathinfo just returns an empty string.

Comment: then use getimagesizefromstring http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php 

I will edit my answer for more clarity

Comment: Thank-you this worked, it returned an object with the image type in it.

Answer (score 1):

Google wont return a file with a suffix. Try `mime_content_type($response)` and then parse the response to figue out the correct suffix

Answer (score 0):

You can use pathinfo to get the extension.

```
$extension = pathinfo($response, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```